# Distinguish different type of input (BASH)

Tags: bash

I have a script that must be able to accept both by files and stdin on the first argument. Then if more or less than 1 arguments, reject them

The goal that I'm trying to accomplish is able to accpet using this format

```
./myscript myfile 

AND 

./myscript < myfile
```

What I have so far is

```
if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then             #check argument
      if [ -t 0 ]; then             #check whether input from keyboard (read from github)
         VAR=${1:-/dev/stdin}       #get value to VAR
         #then do stuff here!!
      else                          #if not input from keyboard
         VAR=$1
         if [ ! -f "$VAR" ]; then   #check whether file readable
            echo "ERROR!"
         else
            #do stuff heree!!!
         fi
      fi
```

fi

The **PROBLEM** is when I tried to say

```
./myscript < myfile
```

it prints

```
ERROR!
```

I dont know whether this is the correct way to do this, I really appreciate for suggestion or the correct code for my problem. Thank you

Comment: `< myfile` reads the contents of the file into the script. It does not give the file as an argument

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

# if nothing passed in command line pass "/dev/stdin" to myself
# so all below code can be made branch-free
[[ ${#} -gt 0 ]] || set -- /dev/stdin

# loop through the command line arguments, treating them as file names
for f in "$@"; do
    echo $f
    [[ -r $f ]] && while read line; do echo 'echo:' $line; done < $f
done
```

Examples:

```
$ args.sh < input.txt
$ args.sh input.txt
$ cat input.txt | args.sh
```

Comment: A downvote from me for just dumping code without explanations.

Comment: Thank you for adding the explanations. Downvote removed.

Comment: `set -- /dev/stdin` will set one argument as the literal string `/dev/stdin`

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９ - good observation, that's exactly what it does. /dev/stdin is a special file in Posix OS-es "containing" the standard input of the process